react router dom loader defer type problem

I tried to solve the problem when loading data by using defer in the loader function.

I don't know how to set the postResponse type, which is the actual response data.

Even if I try type casting or giving any, it doesn't work.


This is the code of the loader function:
export const listPageLoader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const query = request.url.split("?")[1];
  const postPromise: Promise<GetPosts> = apiRequest("/posts?" + query);
  return defer({
    postResponse: postPromise,
  });  
};

This is the code where an error occurs:
<Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
  <Await
    resolve={data.postResponse}
    errorElement={<p>Error loading posts!</p>}
  >
    {({ postResponse }: { postResponse: GetPosts }) => {
      //  {postResponse}
      console.log(postResponse);
    }}
  </Await>
</Suspense>

This is the error message
Type '({ postResponse }: {    postResponse: GetPosts;}) => void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode | AwaitResolveRenderFunction'.
  Type '({ postResponse }: {    postResponse: GetPosts;}) => void' is not assignable to type 'AwaitResolveRenderFunction'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
components.d.ts(137, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AwaitProps'
(property) postResponse: GetPosts

If there is anything strange about my code, please let me know.
I thought it would be possible to access the data through postResponse without an error occurring.
Even if I search, I won't find any similar cases.

You can access search params in a simpler way like this: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader#request

@DrewReese I agree! I just noticed that you manually parse the search params and construct the new url. The docs recommends a different way. Both solutions works of course and it might be that your solution works better for your use case. I just wanted to let you know in case you missed it.

@AlexanderWiklund I was confused by your comment since you directed it at me and I hadn't said anything about processing query strings, but I see in your comment you implied using a URLSearchParams object over direct string processing. Sorry, I misunderstood what you were linking to, I thought you were referencing the params property passed to the loader, which come from the route path definition. Yes, I agree that using the URLSearchParams constructor is an objective improvement.


If there is anything strange about my code, please let me know.
I thought it would be possible to access the data through postResponse
without an error occurring.

Yes, the Await component's children render function doesn't return valid JSX. You are trying to render an anonymous function ({ postResponse }: { postResponse: GetPosts }) => void, it's the void that isn't assignable to React.ReactNode that is expected to be rendered.
<Await
  resolve={data.postResponse}
  errorElement={<p>Error loading posts!</p>}
>
  {({ postResponse }: { postResponse: GetPosts }) => {
    // You can console log here
    console.log(postResponse);

    // But you still need to return valid JSX, example:
    // return <Posts posts={postResponse} />;
    return null;
  }}
</Await>


thank you
It solved it perfectly.
It had to return valid JSX.
